# Thymeleaf's <th> not working at runtime

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to run this links with thymeleaf but it doesnt work
, the static version with th: runs fine but when using jetty  and trying to get thesame css files at run time it does not work

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../../resources/static/css/font-awesome.min.css"
              th:href="@{/resources/static/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="../../resources/static/css/bootstrap.css"
              th:href="@{/resources/static/css/bootstrap.css}">
```

Comment: It's absolutely unclear from your question what is the reason of the issue, try to add more details of your project, error message etc. Did you add Thymeleaf namespace <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> in the html tag?

Comment: yes i added , what i am saying is href = link works when i acces static page but at run time it should use th:href but it just shows my page without the design i have created

Comment: What is your project structure?

Comment: how can i explain the structure? its multi modular now but this webapp -resources - static -css -(this is what i want to acces with th:

Comment: Is it Spring project? How ServletContextTemplateResolver is configured?

Comment: yes it is a spring mvc project

Comment: Try to refer your bootstrap.css as <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @DimaSan you mean to remove the path directory i did that well did not include text/css will try now with type/css

Comment: no it doesnt change anything, could it be a problem with http://localhost:63342 because even if i erase all the html content or select all and comment all , it still shows the static page , it should not show anything if i delete the content of the html page

Comment: Seems like you open is from the Intellij IDEA, that is why your port is 63342. Jetty's default port is 8080, so make sure your app is actually running.

Comment: yeah what i am saying is it works fine when i open from  localhost:63342 but when  i run  from localhost:8080  i get the page without css design

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but most probably that nobody here would like to ask you many times for clarifications and pull the details out of you. You are interested in getting answer for your question. So care to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), provide as many details as you can, including general project structure, question-related dependencies info, configuration, error/log messages and so on. I'll suggest to close your question, until you edit it and make more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing your app from `http://localhost:8080`, try removing the absolute path.

See if this works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/resources/static/css/font-awesome.min.css}"
    href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    th:href="@{/resources/static/css/bootstrap.css}"
    href="/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Also, try to access you css on the browser URL to see if it shows its content:

```
http://localhost:8080/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/css/bootstrap.css
```

Hope it's somehow useful.